# Check whether shortcut key exists/don't allow shortcut key to mutliple actions

Tags: shortcut

Is there an easy way to check whether a shortcut key exists already? I wanted to assign `ctrl+s` as "mark seam" but immediately realized that that was already the save shortcut. I'd like to be able to check whether there would be a double assignment, and if possible, not allow them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an addon already built into Blender (but not on by default) called "Is Key Free". It allows you to enter a key and check it for its uses. After turning on the addon, open the Text Editor, and look in the sidebar to the right of it for the Dev tab. Under that is where you will find the Is Key Free addon, once it has been activated.

Answer (score 3):

Header > Edit > Preferences > Keymap ....

[image]

... search as shown, with a string representation of your shortcut.

You will be shown a list of context-dependent uses of the key combination.